# Bootstrap - Responsive Menu Fix

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.bootply.com/jwGIUdSuHM

I am using Bootstrap, and I have two menus at the top. Once I make my window narrow, my "responsive view" looks like this when I click on My Account. Notice the overlapping options (not good). How can I fix that?

[image]

I've tried setting this to 700 instead of approximately 300 pixels:

```
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse { max-height: 700px; }
```

... and although the problem is gone, it doesn't quite do it for me, because it makes my menu stretch way to long on a phone. So how can I fix that ugly overlap while keeping my menu the same height?

CSS

```
body { margin-top: 125px; }

h1 {text-transform:uppercase;}

/* Header Nav*/
#faves, #cart {border:none;}
#nav {text-transform:uppercase;}
.multi-col-4 {width:820px;}
.multi-col-2 {width:400px;}


 @media (max-width: 890px) {
    body { margin-top: 65px; }

    /* Nav*/
    .multi-col {width:100%;}
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                <button id="faves" type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-link btn-lg"> <span class="sr-only">Favorites</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                <button id="cart" type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-link btn-lg"> <span class="sr-only">Shopping Cart</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a> </div>
            <!-- end navbar-header -->

            <div id="nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <div id="navTop" class="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown hidden-xs"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cart (2) <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View Cart</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown hidden-xs"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Favorites (6) <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View All Favorites</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Option a</a> </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="multi-col multi-col-4">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Option 2</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Option 6</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 7</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 8</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 9</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 10</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 11</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 12</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 13</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Option 14</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 15</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 16</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 17</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 18</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 19</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 20</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Option 21</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 21</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 22</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 23</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 24</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Option 25</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="navBottom" class="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option b <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="multi-col multi-col-4">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">Another action</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">Another action</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">Other Products</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">Another action</li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            </ul>

                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option c <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option d <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option e <span class="caret"></span></a>
                             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="multi-col multi-col-2">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Account</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Tools</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option f <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="multi-col multi-col-2">
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Account</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4" role="menu">
                                            <li class="dropdown-header">Tools</li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Option g <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end nav --> 
        </div>
        <!-- end container-fluid --> 
    </nav>


</form>
```

Comment: I think you need a `class=clearfix` somewhere in there.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/jwGIUdSuHM Bootply example for you; feel free to edit into your question.

Comment: ^ thanks, adding the link

Comment: I tried adding clearfix in a bunch of places, nothing helps. I feel it's something with the max-height of the top menu... but there is no such thing set in CSS that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved with these two lines:

```
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse { max-height: none; }
#nav {max-height:400px;}
```